# How to statically link to a DLL function that is exported by an ordinal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll, dllimport

Say, if a DLL has a function:

```
int TestFunc01(int v)
{
    WCHAR buff[256];
    ::StringCchPrintf(buff, _countof(buff), L"You passed a value of %d", v);
    return ::MessageBox(NULL, buff, L"Test Dll Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

that is exported by its ordinal value only (the following is a `.def` file):

```
LIBRARY   DllName
EXPORTS
   TestFunc01   @1 NONAME
```

So now when I want to statically link to that function from another module, I'd do the following if the function was exported by its name:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int TestFunc01(int v);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestFunc01(123);
}
```

But how do I statically link to it only by its ordinal value?

PS. I'm using a Visual Studio C++ compiler & linker.

Comment: when you build project which export some functions - the lib file always automatically will be created. you simply need include this lib file to linker input to another project, where you want import this function. does not matter are function will be exported by name or ordinal - the `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int TestFunc01(int v);` + lib file will be worked. because you not explicit specify calling convention - both projects must have the same

Comment: @RbMm: Sure, it will work as you described if I remove `NONAME` from the `.def` file. But that is not the point. I'm asking about statically linking to that function using the ordinal function number. Otherwise if I try to compile the second module with the `.lib` file from the DLL above, it will compile OK but the linker will issue `TestFunc01` as undeclared function error and won't link.

Comment: no, this is perfect working with `NONAME` too

Comment: @RbMm: :) Well I'm sitting in front of a VS 2013 linker that gives me that error.

Comment: this **not depend form VS** at all. look in your lib file - in which form `TestFunc01` here ? and which is unresolved symbol (exactly name) reported linker  ?

Comment: only if you not use `PRIVATE` option for function - it name exist in lib file. will be `__imp_*TestFunc01*` symbol in lib. you need look exactly form for `__imp_*TestFunc01*` in lib binary, and also exactly error from linker. and compare this 2 names. nay be calling convention different, or c++/c

Comment: `int TestFunc01(int v)` - you not declare it as `extern "C"` in dll ? yes ? so why you using `extern "C"` in exe ? remove `extern "C"` in exe or add it to dll

Comment: i guess that in lib you have something like `__imp_?TestFunc01@@YAHH@Z` but when you build exe - linker search for when `__imp_TestFunc01` - simply declare it as `__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl TestFunc01(int v);` or which calling convention you use ?

Comment: @RbMm: Oh, shoot. I see your point. I need to quit. It's too late. I'm making silly mistakes. :) I declared it as C++ function and was calling it as a C one. Doh! So if I add `extern "C"` to the definition in the DLL, it all starts to work. I also learned something about the `.lib` files. It does contain that function name, although it is not included in the `.dll` itself. Hah. Interesting. Anyway, thanks dude. And Happy New Year everyone!

Comment: or, better, you can remove `extern "C"` from exe declaration. anyway you need one declaration for both modules. if you want remove name from lib - use `PRIVATE` option. but in this case you lost ability static link with this symbol. with `NONAME` - name of symbol still exist in lib file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how do I statically link to it only by its ordinal value?

absolute the same way, when function exported by name - no any difference. in both case you need 2 things - correct declaration of the function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int /*calling convention*/ TestFunc01(int v);
```

and lib file, included to linker input.

when you include *somename.def* file to visual studio project, it automatically add `/def:"somename.def"` option to linker (otherwise you need manual add this option). generated lib file will be containing `__imp_*TestFunc01*` symbol - in place * will be different decoration based on *c* or *c++* symbol and calling convention, in case *x86*.

from another side, when you call function, with `__declspec(dllimport)` attribute. compiler (*CL*) will be generate `call [__imp_*TestFunc01*]` - so reference to `__imp_*TestFunc01*` symbol (again * in place actual decoration). linker will be search for `__imp_*TestFunc01*` symbol and found it in lib file.

the `NONAME` option does not matter for this process - this this only affects how it will be formed *IAT/INT* entry for this function in *PE* (will be it imported by name or ordinal)

note that if we separate generate lib file from def file only, by `link.exe /lib /def:somename.def` - the linker will be have not correct declarations for exported functions (def file containing name only without calling convention and c or c++ name) - so it always will be considered symbols as `extern "C"` and `__cdecl`

---

in concrete case visible that in dll function implemented as `int TestFunc01(int v)` - so without `extern "C"` - as result in lib file will be symbol like `__imp_?TestFunc01@@YAHH@Z` (i assume *__cdecl* and *x86*), but in another module function used with **`extern "C"`** - so linker will be search for `__imp__TestFunc01` and of course not found it, because it not exist in lib file. because this, when we export/import some symbol - it must be **equal** declared for both modules. the best declare it in separate *.h* file with explicit calling convention

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, you're correct. My bad. Just from curiosity though. You've been really helpful to me on this forum. How do you know all the answers so quickly? :)

Comment: Surely there's no need for dllimport here. We have a lib file that defines the function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - *a lib file that defines the function* - no, lib file nothing defined. here place where linker search for symbols. but this is not definition for compiler. also exist serious different when we use or not use `__declspec(dllimport)` - in case we use it - compiler generate call - `call [__imp_*TestFunc01*]` and linker will be search for `__imp_*TestFunc01*` symbol (which is also implicit `selectany` type). in case we not use `dllimport` - compiler generate call `call *TestFunc01*` and linker wich will be search for `*TestFunc01*` symbol.

Comment: in this case will be stub `jmp [__imp_*TestFunc01*]` in code

Comment: Compiler doesn't need definition, only declaration. The linker needs definitions and in this case finds it in the lib file. I still don't see any need for dllimport here. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan lib file containing both (2) symbols - `__imp_*TestFunc01*` (this is selectany type symbol and just pointer to function) and  `*TestFunc01*` symbol - with is actually stub function (code) - `jmp [__imp_*TestFunc01*]` (and this is not selectany symbol). which from this 2 symbols will be used - depended from `__declspec(dllimport)` usage

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - *What happens if you remove it?* - i describe different - it will be. better of course use `__declspec(dllimport)` anyway. and for definition vs declaration - sorry, my mistake (by english misunderstand at begin)

Comment: Again, I don't see any need for dllimport here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, this is optional in this case, but anyway will be better use it - for what use `call XXX` and `XXX: jmp [__imp_XXX]` construction when we can use `call [__imp_XXX]` just ? not a big different but anyway. also why almost all winapi declared with `dllimport` ? and will be different if 2 libraries containing the same symbol - if we use `__imp_XXX` form - will be no error, linker simply select first library in order for this symbol. in case we use `XXX` - linker produce error - multiple defined symbols

Comment: so to speak - i described different between use or not use `__declspec(dllimport)`. already concrete programmer can select use or not `__declspec(dllimport)` based on understanding what is `dllimport` give and change

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Hmm. You raised an interesting point. I always used `__declspec(dllimport)` without thinking twice about it. So now I had to run some tests to see the difference. I posted a separate answer with the results.

Comment: @c00000fd - but i already explain different - if you use `__declspec(dllimport)` - will be `call [__imp_*]` in code, if you not use it - will be `call X; X: jmp [__imp_*]` in code. this is most visible effect. exist also thin point, if several libs/obj containing `X` or `__imp_X` - with multiple `X` will be error, with multiple `__imp_X` - no error

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, I can see that. I'm trying to understand now why is `dllimport` even exists? Or, I should better say, when we compile a function call without `__declspec(dllimport)` the linker generates that `call X; X: jmp [__imp_*]` construct. So what is the reason for this relative `call` then an absolute `jmp` construct? I hope I'm clear with this. It's hard to explain with words in this little window.

Comment: @c00000fd - if function `X` not marked with `__declspec(dllimport)`- compiler assume that this is usual function and generate `call X`. later, at link time - linker search for `X` symbol - if found it in import library. implement body-stub `X: jmp [__imp_X]`. in case we mark function with `dllimport` - compiler just generate `call [__imp_X]` instead at `call X`. and linker search for `__imp_X` symbol. however modern `CL` have `/GL` option (link time code generation). with it (and `/LTCG` linker option) even if you call import function not marked with `dllimport` linker remove `jmp` stub

Comment: @c00000fd - read also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russellk/2005/03/20/lnk4217/ - this is old article, before [`/GL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8.aspx) and [/LTCG (Link-time Code Generation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx). so when you use this options - code will changed - you never view `call X; X: jmp [__imp_X]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the lib.exe tool to create a .lib file from a .DEF file that you write, you do not have to actually provide any object files.

You would write a .def that matches the ordinals you want to export but also provide names and then use lib.exe to create a .lib.

In code you would then declare it as:
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) ret_type funcName(arg_type);

It is important that the calling convention match whatever the function actually uses but the name would have to match what your created .lib uses even if that name doesn't follow the decoration normal for that call type.

Comment: *you do not have to actually provide any object files* - no, this is error. in this case lib file can not containing **correct** names for symbols on x86 platform. because it simply have not it definitions. any symbol will be be considered as `extern "C"` and `__cdecl`. so this will be not work for c++ symbols and for not `__cdecl` functions on *x86*. say if `TestFunc01` declared as `__sdtcall` - with normal lib file build (including  objects) `__imp__TestFunc01@4` symbol will be in lib, but with def file only - `__imp__TestFunc01`

Answer (score 0):

This is not to compete with the [actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48048523/843732). *David Heffernan* raised a good point in the comments there, about the use of `dllimport`. So I thought to make several tests to see what difference does it make when I use `__declspec(dllimport)` and when I don't:

## 1. x86 release build

Function declaration in the DLL:

```
extern "C" int __cdecl TestFunc01(int v)
{
    WCHAR buff[256];
    ::StringCchPrintf(buff, _countof(buff), L"You passed a value of %d", v);
    return ::MessageBox(NULL, buff, L"Test Dll Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

then import and call it from another module:

### With `__declspec(dllimport)`

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl TestFunc01(int v);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestFunc01(123);
}
```

compiled machine code:

[image]

The `call` instruction reads the function address from the *Import Address Table* (IAT):

[image]

that gives it the location of imported function:

[image]

---

### Without `__declspec(dllimport)`

```
extern "C" int __cdecl TestFunc01(int v);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestFunc01(123);
}
```

compiled machine code:

[image]

In this case it is a relative `call` to a single `jmp` instruction:

[image]

which in turn reads the function address from IAT:

[image]

and jumps to it:

[image]

---

## 2. x64 release build

For 64-bit we have to change the calling convention to `__fastcall`. The rest stays the same:

### With `__declspec(dllimport)`

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __fastcall TestFunc01(int v);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestFunc01(123);
}
```

compiled machine code:

[image]

Again the `call` instruction reads the function address from IAT (in case of x64 it uses relative address):

[image]

that gives it the function address:

[image]

---

### Without `__declspec(dllimport)`

```
extern "C" int __fastcall TestFunc01(int v);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestFunc01(123);
}
```

compiled machine code:

[image]

Again a relative `call` to a single `jmp`:

[image]

that in turn reads the function address from IAT:

[image]

and jumps to it:

[image]

## Conclusion

So as you see, by not using `dllimport` you're technically incurring an additional `jmp`. I'm not exactly sure what is the purpose of that jump, but it is sure not to make your code run faster. Maybe it's a code maintenance thing, maybe it's a way to do *hot-patching* for updates, maybe a debugging feature. So if someone can shed some light on the purpose of that jump I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: In terms of performance when calling it's unlikely to make much difference, and until you've measured you are foolish to make too many assumptions.

Comment: It means there is a single address to perform relocation fixups on, rather than one per call to the function.

Comment: I'm not sure you're gonna win anything with relocations. Here's the breakdown for the number of relocations needed for each case: x86 with dllimport = 2, x86 without dllimport = 2, x64 with dllimport = 1, x64 without dllimport = 1. So there must be something else. @RbMm do you know?

Comment: Don't you need one relocation per call with DllImport?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you look at my screenshots above: `x86 with dllimport`, obviously there's one relocation needed for the Import Address Table (there's no way to avoid that) and then the second relocation for the `call` instruction itself. In x86 it can't use relative addresses for dereferencing, i.e. `call dword ptr [addr]`. So this machine code needs to be relocated too: `FF, 15, XX, XX, XX, XX`. For `x86 without dllimport` the `call` is relative but `jmp` is not. So this needs to be relocated as well besides its IAT entry: `FF, 25, XX, XX, XX, XX`. So this makes it 2 for both.

Comment: I thought there needed to be one relocation per call. You can't discern anything from your post because we don't know what module these addresses are in

Comment: What difference does the module do? It's a flat addressing space anyway. I showed you the machine code for each instruction that shows the difference.

Comment: I was thinking that the table was in the target module, the callee. But it's in the caller isn't it? That's what I was misthinking.

Comment: Yes, the IAT of interest is in the module that imports and calls the function. In my case, the IAT I referred to in my screenshots is in the exe module. The function called, `TestFunc01` is in the DLL. But again, modules become irrelevant once the module is mapped and rebased in the target process. Then it's just an address in a process' flat addressing space.

Comment: If the address was in the other module then every call would need a relocation. That was my misthink and why I was referring to the module. But if it was done that way then the call would not need to be indirect.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, the relocations happen once when a module is loaded into a process (if rebasing is needed, which is almost always the case with ASLR these days.) The reason we need relocations is to patch all absolute addresses/dereferencing in x86 code, and some in x64. In case of IAT, relocations are always needed as function addresses change depending on the virtual base address where the module (DLL) is mapped into the process memory.

Comment: Yes I understand now. I was explaining my misthink, which was that the table was in the other module. Which would imply a relocation for every reference to that table.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah, I see.

Comment: and i sure you compile and build without *Use Link Time Code Generation* - on this in project option - and view change - no more will be jmp even without dllimport

Comment: *some light on the purpose of that jump* - no any purpose. but if you not mark function with `dlimport` compiler can not know that this is imported api. he assume that this is usual function and generate `call X` (relative call). only at link time linker found that this is imported api. but he already can not change this `call X` (he can only fix relative offset - 4 bytes). so linker and generate stub `X: jmp [__imp_X]`. change this can by 2 way - give knowledge for compiler that this is imported api - as result compiler generate indirect `call [__imp_X] `

Comment: or use modern link time code generation options, let linker optimize it. however if call api from asm you need yourself select `call X` or `call [__imp_X]`

Comment: @RbMm: OK. It makes sense now. Thanks for the info. So yeah, if you're using an older linker, it does make sense to use `__declspec(dllimport)` all the time. Although with the modern wasteful ways of programming, no one will miss lost CPU cycles on that one `jmp`, I'm sure, right?

Comment: need both compiler (/GL) and linker (/LTCG) options. you can set it now in you project and look how changed code without dllimport. the jmp instruction of course not fastest (run out of instruction cache) but usual this is nothing with time of executed api.

Comment: Basically, when writing a program, you shouldn't know or care where called functions will be resolved from: dll or static library. That's what linker is supposed to handle -- and it does handle it; but if you wish, you can save one JMP instruction on each function-call if you use declspec(dllimport).